# What can I use as an equivalent component to these in Eagle?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, multiplexer

I just wanted to ask you if I can use SN74154N as a library and, hopefully, it would be same size (pins, etc..) as my original component MH74154.

Also, what component would you recommend instead of MH7404 hex inverter in Eagle? It should also be the same width, pinout number and so on..

I want to use all of these components in my PCB project.

Comment: You just look through all the elements in the eagle library that seem close and if that doesn't work, check the manufacturer's website for materials, if that doesn't work, check for more reputable manufacturers that make the same part.  If that doesn't work you look at the datasheet for the specs and make your own element and footprint in eagle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eagle has generic TTL chips or simply a specific part number from one manufacturer, as it makes no sense to make dozens of identical 7404 chips from all different manufacturers. Just use the generic type and if you want a specific manufacturer for a 7404 chip then edit the properties or the exported BOM to contain that info.

Comment: SN74154N and MH74154 seem to have the same sizing, even the pinout is identical. And I understand. Now I will try to check the inverter.